# using image swap with background-size: contain

Tags: css, hover, contain

I'm not sure what to do. I want to use one image with two different pictures on it for the image swap (on hover) so there won't be a delay due to a new picture having to be loaded.

But, I'm using background-size: contain because there's a lot of changes in the scale of the image depending on a bunch of different factors. Is there a way to make it work? It's just not working for me at all. It tries to fit the entire img into the space instead of just the half that's supposed to go there.

Here's the css:

```
.newbutton a:hover , .newbutton a:active{
    background-image: url(images/new-post-button.png);
    display: block;
    background-color: #9bb6c3;
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
.newbutton a {
    background-color: #c0d6e4;
    background-image: url(images/new-post-button.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;    
}
```

Comment: Contain will not work because it will show the whole image.  You could play around with size and position. Could you post your html?

Comment: Contain will always do what it says--contain your image within the element. If you can assume the width or height will always be 100%, you could work it that way with size and position...